# coding issue due to data type mismatch

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am facing the run time error 3464

this code is working fine for some datatypes. When it encounters the value in the format of data like Engine launch date it is showing run time error.

```
Public Function SearchForID(strTableToSearch As String, strColumnNameToSearch As String, strNewItemName As String) As Integer

    'Varialbes
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim StrValue As String

    'Assigning Database to the Variable db
    Set db = CurrentDb
    'Creating a Query to the Recordset
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & strTableToSearch & " WHERE " & strColumnNameToSearch & " = '" & strNewItemName & "'")
    'We need to check for the valid record set
    rs.FindFirst ("[" & strColumnNameToSearch & "] = '" & strNewItemName & "'")

    If rs.NoMatch Then
       SearchForID = 0
    'If the recordset exists
    Else
    'Returning the ID value to StrValue
        SearchForID = rs.Fields(0)

    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

I expect the code to be executed for all datatypes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering Access report with multiple strings in vba, getting data type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010584/filtering-access-report-with-multiple-strings-in-vba-getting-data-type-mismatch)

Comment: Change strNewItemName to a _Variant_ and apply to linked CSql function to generate the string expression for the value.

Comment: Hello Gustav.. I have tried with the code but the problem is the  launch date which is my current value has to go a particular filed Date in the Ms Access ship information table. In Ship information table the column "Date" data type is date/time. so still facing the issue.

Comment: Yes? So what did you try?

Comment: the code which you have mentioned in the comment one

Comment: OK, but how? Also, you could reveal the resulting SQL string.

Comment: i have changed the data type in the Ms access accordingly now it is working fine